# Adding null/Zero values to comma delimeted file using unix scripting giving issue

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I have a requirment where, I get files from source with different number of delimeter data, i need to make them to one standard number of delimeted data.

i tried below command `sed -i "s/$/0,0,0/" file_nm` : The data is entering at new line as below

source file1:

```
AA,BB,CC,0,0    
AC,BD,DB,1,0   
EE,ER,DR,0,0
```

Result file

```
AA,BB,CC,0,0                                             
,0,0,0     
AC,BD,DB,1,0     
,0,0,0   
EE,ER,DR,0,0  
,0,0,0
```

What i want to do is appened an extra 3 zeros at the end for each row

```
AA,BB,CC,0,0,0,0,0  
AC,BD,DB,1,0,0,0,0  
EE,ER,DR,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: apart from the line break problem, with your input and your code, the line should look like `AA...0,00,0,0` where did the comma come? do you really get the output from your command?

Comment: There are spaces after the lines

Comment: Try `sed "s/ *$/,0,0,0/"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed '1,$ s/$/,0,0,0/' inputfile
```

Here is what I tried

[image]

**P.S.:** Provided the input file columns don't have any space or tab after last column.

Comment: what's the difference between your solution and OPs?

Comment: As per my try OPs solution also working but I don't know why it's not working for him @Kent

Comment: the address `1,$` here is redundant. OP's cmd is better, except for the missing `comma` in his replacement part.

Comment: There is no such tab or space at the end of line,just a line break i have.

Comment: @MaheshRachannavar then it should work as I gave you the screenshot of my terminal alone

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more dynamic solution with **awk**:

```
awk -F, '{i=NF;while(i++<9){$0=$0",0"}}1' File
```

Note: change `9` according to your requirements.

```
Sample:

AMD$ cat File
AA,BB,CC,0,0,0
AC,BD,DB,1,0
EE,ER,DR,0,0,0

AMD$ awk -F, '{i=NF;while(i++<9){$0=$0",0"}}1' File
AA,BB,CC,0,0,0,0,0,0
AC,BD,DB,1,0,0,0,0,0
EE,ER,DR,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Here, we set `,` as the awk delimiter; then, we keep on adding `0` at the end of each line as long as the total number of fields is less than 9. In this case, irrespective of the number of fields, it will add `0`s at the end of each line to make the total number of fields = `9`.

Comment: NOt sure y, but still this command too is adding extra data every new line. Which is not as expected